# Having trouble bootloading my Two-Up printer

Tags: arduino-ide, bootloader, teensy

I am following [these instructions](http://www.fabric8r.com/forums/showthread.php?1308-Customizing-Marlin-Firmware-for-the-One-Up-and-Two-Up) to set up my Two-Up 3D printer, and I have no problems all the way up until step 18.  The board uses the arduino IDE to burn the bootloader, which is why I am posting this here.

I have my board set to "[BootloaderCDC]Teensylu/Printrboard" in the tools menu, and I have selected the appropriate COM port.  I use arduino for tons of other things so I know my way around the IDE reasonably well, but I have never encountered this error before so I'm not quite sure what to make of it or how to fix it.

[Here is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bephe.png)

I have the red board (version 2) and I am using Arduino version 1.0.6.  As far as I can tell, I have perfectly followed all of the steps up until this part with no noticible problems.  I remembered to bridge the boot pins and everything.

In the video the guy says there may be an error when you go to program the board but my error is way different than his error in the video, and hbe says you should hear the dissconnect and reconnect sounds as the board gets reset after a bootload (I didn't hear them).

Anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?